# Acceleration reverses velocity direction

Tags: javascript, typescript, math, physics

I'm trying to create a realistic slot machine animation, where the "spin" (actually a looped translation) gradually slows to a stop at a specified slot image. With my current implementation, it does actually stop at the right image, but it does so by spinning past it, then reversing direction and finally landing at the correct spot.

`displacement = initial_velocity*delta_time + 1/2*acceleration*delta_time^2`
to derive
`acceleration = (2*total_displacement - 2*initial_velocity*delta_time) / delta_time^2`.

```js
private getAnimationDisplacement(): number {
    if(!this.spinInProgress) return 0

    // Time
    const totalDuration = this.machine.spinDuration // ms
    const curTime = new Date()
    const dt = curTime.getTime() - (this.lastFrameTime || this.spinInProgress.startTime).getTime() // ms
    this.lastFrameTime = curTime

    // Calculate total (final) displacement for current spin
    const spinCount         = 1
    const spinOffset        = spinCount * this.spinInProgress.slotFaces // number of faces
    const faceOffset        = this.spinInProgress.getFaceOffset().offset // pixels
    const totalOffset       = new FaceOffset(spinOffset + faceOffset) // pixels
    const totalDisplacement = totalOffset.offset * this.getFaceHeight() // pixels

    // Acceleration
    const acceleration = (2*totalDisplacement - 2*INIT_VELOCITY * totalDuration) / Math.pow(totalDuration, 2) // pixels / ms^2

    // Diplacement
    this.displacement += this.velocity * dt

    // Velocity
    this.velocity += acceleration * dt

    // Modulo by max displacement causes animation to loop
    return this.displacement % this.maxDisplacement
  }
```

I can't figure out how this standard equation of motion is somehow going the right direction, then reversing direction, to finally land at the correct spot. I'm trying to avoid the weird reverse animation. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is correct for normal motion equations. It is commonly referred to as "what goes up must come down" - any negative acceleration (deceleration) will eventually cause an object to move in the opposite direction - such as throwing a ball in the air. The correct way to fix this is to make sure the system stop at the specified slot when velocity reaches zero. This cannot be done by starting at a given position, velocity and acceleration. You need to reverse-calculate the states and select either a position or speed to start with that will give you the result you want

Comment: Another way to fix this is to simply stop when velocity reaches zero - this means you do not specify a slot to end with but simply let the simulation select one for you when velocity is zero.

Comment: @slebetman would `this.velocity = Math.max(0, this.velocity)` solve that? When I add that line after the velocity update, it stops at the wrong slot face...

Comment: With that solution there is no wrong slot face. There is only the slot face you stop at which by definition is the slot face the wheel stops at. If you want to pre-select a slot face then you have to do a reverse simulation first (calculate from the selected slot face with velocity 0 and negative acceleration, count number of seconds, then stop the simulation and find the starting position of the slot and speed - now that you know the starting position animate from there with positive acceleration and you will end up with zero velocity when you reach your destination)